# How to migrate Java EE projects from MyEclipse to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, myeclipse

In my company, we develop a Java EE product in MyEclipse, but now I have to transport all projects to the last version of Eclipse (Eclipse Java EE Juno sr1 x64).

I have no idea what needs to happen. How to carry on and migrate all projects from MyEclipse to plain Eclipse?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the existing workspace, then open this copy with your new eclipse release so you'll see what's going to happen... in fact it is impossible for us to guess as it depends on so many aspects (plugins used, project facets, just Java or Java EE, etc.)

Comment: when i search about migration, it is differences between eclipse based project and myeclipse based project (source, xml defined etc) maybe have to changing some xml definitation so i want to ask. your idea is enough to migration?

Comment: What happened after you tried it?

Comment: alot of error and warning xml defination and errors about classpath

Comment: in this link :   http://nileshk.com/2005/11/03/migrating-myeclipse-to-wtp.html  see something but i can t understand.

Comment: It is quite an old link but the approach should work, though I would modify it: create a basic web project in MyEclipse then create a similar one in Eclipse JEE (it might be called "Dynamic Web Project") and see what the differences are in all the settings files, like .project, .classpath and the other settings files. Use that knowledge to try to migrate an existing MyEclipse web project.

However, the easiest option would be to stay with MyEclipse!